Issue with perl/Tk::Date module
I create a date widget like this:
$GUI{time} = $GUI{timeframe}->Date(-value => ‘now’,
                                   -datefmt => ‘%4y  %2m  %2d,
                                   -timefmt => %2H %2M,
                                   -check => true)->pack;

If I enter a value of 13 in the month field, the widget module fixes it.
If I enter a value of 14 or higher the widget locks up, runs out of Memory and crashes. (THIS IS ISSUE #1)
If I enter an hour greater than 12 the widget allows it to remain there. (THIS IS ISSUE #2)
The widget will fix the hour but onlyif I put in a minute greater than what is allowable. Otherwise it will not fix the hour.
ISSUE #3 is that I can only find this reference for the Date module: https://metacpan.org/pod/Tk::Date. This reference lists bugs at the bottom and one of them is the check function. It also says "command is not fully implemented". Does this mean it is an unreliable module?

See also the module's bugs.

Please provide minimal runnable sample code. See [mcve] for more information

Tk::Date uses Time::Local whose author has actively refused to handle invalid inputs.

Does this mean there is no controlled and constantly repaired perl/Tk software baseline? Does anyone perl/Tk?

Take a look at Tk::DateEntry

Baseline modules are listed here: https://metacpan.org/dist/Tk Tk::Date is not part of the distribution.
